# Solving Lookback Time Integral for the Age of the Universe

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology

The following integral of lookback time gives the age of the Universe with matter (dark + baryonic) density $\Omega_m \approx 0.3154$ and $\Omega_{\Lambda} \approx 1-\Omega_m$, ignoring radiation density and curvature:

$$t_L = (1/H_0) \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dz'}{(1+z')\sqrt{\Omega_m(1+z)^3 + \Omega_{\Lambda}}}$$

where $H_0$ is the current value of Hubble parameter. I took $H(z) = H_0(z)\sqrt{\Omega_m(1+z)^3 + \Omega_{\Lambda}}$.

Can this integral be solved analytically? If so, please provide only a hint to that.

https://www.integral-calculator.com says "Antiderivative or integral could not be found. Note that many functions don't have an elementary antiderivative."

Comment: Looks like it is possible: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+of+dz+%2F+%28%281%2Bz%29*sqrt%28M*%281%2Bz%29%5E3+%2B+L%29%29). But exact analytic formulas in terms of complicated functions are rarely the most important thing in physics.